# How to turnoff IE address bar for Windows Embedded Handheld

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, windows-ce, kiosk-mode, windows-embedded

I am making a web application which has to be used on a PDA (I am not gracefull for this but it is how it is). Now I found [this](http://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/internet-explorer-kiosk-mode.aspx) to turn off browser components to let IE run in Kiosk mode. This does not work for Windows Embedded Handheld which has a non standard mobile version of IE.

Does someone know how I can force IE on Windows Embedded Handheld to kiosk mode or emulate something that has the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already kiosk mode browser apps available by third party providers. There is for example Wavellink and Naurtec and on the other side manufacturers like Intermec by Honeywell that offer kisok mode browsers.

If you have VS2005/VS2008 (no standard or express edition) you can easily write your own kiosk mode browser, just create a form and use the .NET webbrowser object.

Comment: I am making my own Kiosk browser with microsoft .net compact framework 2.0